Generalizing Reidemeister-Singer Theorem to manifolds with boundary
I was studying some Heegaard splittings theory for a course; we saw the Reidemeister-Singer theorem, which states that for a closed, connected 3-manifold $M$, any two Heegaard splittings share a same stabilization.
Since a Heegaard splitting is an intrinsically smooth concept, and since I was presented with a PL/combinatoric proof, I sought a smooth proof, which I found in this article by Jesse Johnson (arXiv:0705.3712), using Morse theory, or a generalization thereof.
Now, I was wondering if there was anything in the way of generalizing this kind of proof to manifolds with boundary (possibly compact), taking generalized Heegaard splittings in compression bodies instead.
I am aware of an article by François Laudenbach (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.1130) which uses more advanced Morse theory techniques, which I am not familiar with, to prove R-S, so I do not really know how (if, even) it could be generalized.
Does anybody have any reference in this matter? Articles, books, pre-prints, anything goes really.
I want to thank in advance everybody who will take some time to answer me.
